# Copied C drive contents to external HDD, half of the content is not there, but content size says otherwise

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive

I copied my C drive onto an external HDD. The folder which holds this shows that it has about 20GB of data.
However, when I open the folder, and check the sum of all contents, it only adds up to about 10GB. All of my important documents and such are no where to be found, the My Document folder isn't even in it!

I tried to show hidden files, but that didn't help. I'm fairly certain that I copied everything over without issues, what could be the problem?

Comment: Interesting... have you tried to run CHKDSK on this external drive to check if it just doesn't lie about used space?

Comment: @Kitet yea, no errors

Comment: Does WinDirStat help to clarify this for you?  See WinDirStat.info ( http://windirstat.info/wds_current_setup.exe for WinDirStat installer).  Have it run on the external drive, and see if it shows you how the 20GB is used up.